# PL/SQL Developer: save current project and all table

Tags: plsqldeveloper

Unluckily, currently I have to work with PL/SQL Developer 12.0.7.

The main question is: how to save current project and all tabs including SQL queries and tables metadata tabs? Without having to manually save all scripts to .sql files.

This one seems such a basic functionality that I feel quite confused if there's simply no such option.

If so, are there any workarounds? Of do I really have to reopen all my 20 metadata tabs and manually save all sctipts tabs?

Thanks in advance!

I've tried "save project" option, but it doesn't work for saving tabs.